# Using python trying to clean and load file, to CSV but empty fields keep displaying double quotes. I would like empty fields to be empty strings

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

My data displays "" in place of empty fields when I convert the file to a CSV. I would like for it to be an empty string using pandas dataframe.

What it looks like

```
10/10/2020                 
10/10/2020
10/10/2020
""
""
```

What I want it to look like

```
10/10/2020                 
10/10/2020
10/10/2020
```

Comment: please share your code snippets to better help you rectify the error

Comment: df.to_csv('PATH.csv', index = False)
df.to_csv('PATH.csv', na_rep = 'NULL', index=False)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your existing dataframe has the following setup:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'a_column': ['10/10/2020', '10/10/2020', '10/10/2020', '', '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Replace empty strings with np.NaN
df.replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

Then, you can try either one of these options:

```py
# Option 1: Keep rows with np.NaN but replace
df.to_csv('output1.csv', na_rep='NULL', index=False)

# Option 2: Drop rows with np.NaN values
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.to_csv('output2.csv', index=False)
```

`output1.csv`:

```
a_column
10/10/2020
10/10/2020
10/10/2020
NULL
NULL
```

`ouptut2.csv`:

```
a_column
10/10/2020
10/10/2020
10/10/2020
```

EDIT: Changed starting dataframe after clarification from reporter.

Comment: I am reading an excel file into a pandas dataframe and altering the data, I have gotten the Nan to remove from the dataframe but not the "" from the CSV

Comment: Neither option works, second deletes all the data in the column

Comment: this is incorrect the CSV output consists of double quotes.

Comment: It did not work there are still double quotes

Comment: @pixies1997: Please update your question and add the code where you create the (simplified) dataframe, so that we can start at the same point.